# How do I retain inheritance information in a flattened Redux store?

Tags: inheritance, reactjs, redux

I am using Redux for state management in a React application. I also intend to “flatten” any API responses in order to encourage reuse and reduce data duplication across the state tree. I am hoping to use [Normalizr](https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr) to achieve this.

My question is about the preferred way of managing relationships between objects - particularly inheritance-type relationships.

The application makes requests to an API (backend written in Java, Spring). The Domain Model that has been defined includes relationships such as:

```
interface NamedThing {
    int getId();
    String getName();
}

interface Pet extends NamedThing {
    Person getOwner();
}

class Cat implements Pet {
    int getId() {
        ...
    };
    String getName() {
        ...
    };
    Person getOwner() {
        ...
    };
    int getNumberOfLivesRemaining() {
        …
    };
}

class Dog implements Pet {
    int getId() {
        ...
    };
    String getName() {
        ...
    };
    Person getOwner() {
        ...
    };
    int getAgeInDogYears() {
        …
    };
}

class Person implements NamedThing {
    int getId() {
        ...
    };
    String getName() {
        ...
    };
}
```

A response for a GET request to a /pets endpoint might look like:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    type: ‘cat',
    name: ‘Fluffy',
    owner: {
        id: 1,
        name: ‘Mary'
    },
    numberOfLivesRemaining: 9
},
{
    id: 2,
    type: ‘dog',
    name: ‘Ralph',
    owner: {
        id: 1,
        name: ‘Mary'
    },
    ageInDogYears: 10
}]
```

With the correct schemas defined, Normalizr would flatten the response to something like this:

```
{
    result: [
        {id: 1, schema: ‘cats’},
        {id: 2, schema: ‘dogs’}
    ],
    entities: {
        cats: {
            1: {
                id: 1,
                type: ‘cat’,
                name: ‘Fluffy’,
                owner: 1,
                numberOfLivesRemaining: 9
            }
        },
        dogs: {
            2: {
                id: 2,
                type: ‘dog',
                name: ‘Ralph',
                owner: 1,
                ageInDogYears: 10
            }
        },
        persons: {
            1: {
                id: 1,
                name: ‘Mary’
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Approach 1:

The different entities (cats, dogs and persons) could be stored in similarly named collections in the application state. However, I would lose the detail that the cats and dogs were pets, which I know since I made a call to the pets endpoint.

#### Approach 2:

I could store all pet entities in a pets collection and store the ids of all of the cats and the ids of all of the dogs in separate collections. I would then be able to pass all of the cats, all of the dogs or all of the pets into a component by using the [React-Redux](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux) mapStateToProps function to filter accordingly.

However, if I make a GET request to a /namedThings endpoint I would have cats, dogs and persons returned and store them in a namedThings collection, with collections for the ids of cats, dogs and persons. But, again, I do not know that the cats and dogs are also pets since this information is not contained within the API response.

To address this, I could:

1. Change the API so that the super-type information is contained in the response
2. Map both the collections for cats and dogs to a merged component “prop” that contains all pets
3. Have the reducers know that a cat is a pet and therefore add an id to the pet id collection when adding a cat to the store.

What is the best approach for representing this type of entity hierarchy when using Redux and Normalizr? How are other teams solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these approaches sound fine:

> 2. Map both the collections for cats and dogs to a merged component “prop” that contains all pets
> 3. Have the reducers know that a cat is a pet and therefore add an id to the pet id collection when adding a cat to the store.

You should try them both and see what makes more sense for your application.

Comment: Thanks for your response Dan, and for Redux et al!

Just to be explicit, the suggestion was that; 

2. stores each entity type in a separate collection and
3. stores all NamedThing subclass entities in a single collection.

Is there a preferred approach to the storing of entities like this in Redux?

Could you please suggest what the pros and cons of these two approaches might be, or provide some criteria for assessing which could work best for my application? i.e. what are the implications for testing and performance?

Comment: I don't see any important difference. I can't assess what's best because I didn't see the UI, the data model, the requirements, etc.